# What does the graph of line L(x,y) look like? where (x,y)$\in C^2$ and L(x,y) is a linear equation of x and y

Tags: algebraic-geometry

And after compactifying by adding the infinite point, why the line L(x,y) will turn to be the complex sphere $C_{\infty}$? For the second question, I think as the value of x can be the whole complex Surface $C$, and so does y, so how could these two variables degenerate to the $C_{\infty}$?

Comment: It might help to define more of your notation.

Comment: @Michael Burr, sorry about that, but what definition do you feel confused about?

Comment: Do you have a general line or are you looking at a particular line?  What do you mean by the "graph" of the line, the variety?

Comment: @Michael Burr I mean the general case, but if you want we can consider the case x+y=0. (x,y)$\in C^2$

Comment: It's hard to describe the object that you're considering because it's in 4 real dimensional space (2 complex dimensional).  In the real plane, what you're doing is taking a line and identifying the endpoints to get a circle.  In the 2 complex dimensional space, a line is locally 2 real dimensional.  So, you could think of it like taking a real plane and identifying all the "infinite edges" of the plane in a point.  It's like turing a line into a circle, but much harder to visualize because of the higher dimensions.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Michael Burr, Thank you very much, actually my main question is the my second question, but I don't know how to see that thus I think maybe I need to see the line before compactifying. And how do you think about the second one?

Comment: Even though there are two variables, they are dependent on each other, so you really only have one variable (if you look at a line $ax+by=0$, you only need to be careful when either $a$ or $b$ is zero.  In all other cases, you can just use either the $x$ or the $y$ and they give you the same space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22168/discussion-between-joseph-and-michael-burr).